# Every time i add new data, all the values in the select option will save to all database. i want to save only the selected option. Php, Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have this javascript CODE in **index.php**:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.first_name', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id1");  
           var first_name = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, first_name, "first_name");  
      });  
      $(document).on('blur', '.last_name', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var last_name = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id,last_name, "last_name");  
      });
      $(document).on('blur', '.gender', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id3");  
           var gender= $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id,gender, "gender");  
      });
```

AND in **select.php**:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td class="first_name" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["first_name"].'</td>  
                     <td class="last_name" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["last_name"].'</td>  
                     <td><select class="type" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'">  
                               <option>'.$row["gender"].'</option>  
                               <option>male</option>
                               <option>female</option>                                 
                          </select></td> 
                     <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }
```

ALSO in **edit.php** here:

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  
 $id = $_POST["id"];  
 $text = $_POST["text"];  
 $column_name = $_POST["column_name"];  
 $sql = "UPDATE tbl_sample SET ".$column_name."='".$text."' WHERE id='".$id."'";  
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
 {  
      echo 'Data Updated';  
 }  
 ?>
```

My question is, everytime i add new data, all the text in gender option will save to database. i want to save only the selected option. Please help me.

Comment: I don't see anything that makes a POST request, you should post your ajax call. I do see an sql injection problem though. Apart from a prepared statement, you will need a white-list for your column name.

Comment: Your question title should be a question not a list of tags.

Comment: im sorry my question it at the bottom. btw, other values are perfectly working fine. just for the select option in gender. it saved all option in the database. @jeroen

Comment: I know it's at the bottom, but if you want people to find and bother to read your question the title should ask a clear question.

Comment: yeah my bad. i will do it next time. thanks

Comment: _Do it this time!_ Or your question is likely to be closed as "Unclear what you are asking. Questions on SO should be useful for future visitors who may be experiencing the same problem. Without a clear description, your question is unlikely to appear in searches and is therefore useless to the community.

Comment: i will i will. i want to edit the title but i don't know how. Next time ill do it right. Thanks

Comment: There is an edit button right there under your question.

Comment: Thank you sir @Turnip, i already change the title. i'm sorry i'm just new. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> all the text in gender option will save to database

Well yes, this is what happens when you use `$(this).text();`

Gender is a select input, not a text field (where `.text()` works fine). Therefore you should use

```
var gender= $(this).val();
```

<sub>Edit: it's `.val()`, not `.value()`</sub>

Comment: i've changed it but still doesn't work. It still save all the option. Btw, Thanks for your answer @Cashbee.

Comment: Wow! awesome sir. you made my day. Thank you very much. You solve my problem for the last two days i'm worrying about. hehe i was thinking to quit coding.:D

Comment: PS: I would recommend you use .val() also for the text field inputs

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('blur', '.type', function(){  
   var id = $(this).data("id3");
   var gender= $(this).val();
   edit_data(id,gender, "gender");
});
```

Use this code for update user gender type in database.

First you get wrong element for gender please use **.type** not **.gender** and 2nd you grab all the text in dropdown it's not good code practice. use this `.val()` not `.text()` on **input** fields.

PHP code

```
        $m = $row["gender"] == "male" ? "selected" : "";
        $f = $row["gender"] == "female" ? "selected" : "";
         $output .= '
               <tr>
                    <td class="first_name" data-id1="' . $row["id"] . '" contenteditable>' . $row["first_name"] . '</td>
                    <td class="last_name" data-id2="' . $row["id"] . '" contenteditable>' . $row["last_name"] . '</td>
                    <td><select class="type" data-id3="' . $row["id"] . '">
                              <option>select</option>
                              <option value="male" ' . $m .'>male</option>
                              <option value="female" '. $f .'>female</option>
                         </select></td>
                    <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="' . $row["id"] . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>
               </tr>
          ';
```